# asset_path / image_path is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

In my html, I have this partial that i want to render x1000 :

```
<div data-image-url="<%= image_path("placeholders/#{object.placeholder_name}") %>"></div>
```

And the results is slow, between 5 and 40ms per view rendering, so > 15s for the full page :

```
  ...
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (15.6ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (7.0ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (5.9ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (8.7ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (10.3ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (9.4ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (5.4ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (38.5ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (9.8ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (6.8ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (7.9ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered default_services/_default_service.html.erb (5.6ms)
  ...
```

(When I comment out 'image_path', it is 0.1 or 0.2ms per view rendering.)

=> Is it possible to make "image_path" faster, (except using cache)?

(I am caching the whole thing so in the end, the total 1000x rendering is <10ms but still wondering)

Answer (score 1):

Is problem occurs in development mode? Only with images?

Usually development server is [webrick](https://rubygems.org/gems/webrick), that has this problems.
Try change webrick to another server (eg [thin](https://rubygems.org/gems/thin)).

Also You may turn off debug mode:

```
# development.rb
config.assets.debug = false
```

Answer (score 1):

When rails is run in development mode, all assets are served independently, and they are fetchd from the app/assets folder. This is done by sprockets so that modifications to the original assets can be instantly seen in the webpage. In production the assets are moved to the public folder.

I'm not sure this is the cause of the issue, but you can give it a try by disabling assets degub mode:

```
 config.assets.debug = false
```

Let me know if that helps at all.